# Connect database using JSP

Tags: database, jsp

I connected to database using jdbc driver in JSP and I want to learn what is the best way to connect database? 
Connect database in `jsp` is a good way? 
if not what is the best way ?

Comment: JSP is more ideal for view part of MVC . fetch from servlet and serve to jsp . still if you need you have JSTL - sql tags
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_sql_setdatasource_tag.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Programming Practices**

In general, avoid writing Java code (declarations, scriptlets and expressions) in your JSP pages, for the following reasons:

- Syntax errors in Java code in a JSP page are not detected until the page is deployed. Syntax errors in tag libraries and servlets, on the other hand, are detected prior to deployment.
- Java code in JSP pages is harder to debug.
- Java code in JSP pages is harder to maintain, especially for page authors who may not be Java experts.
- It is generally accepted practice not to mix complex business logic with presentation logic. JSP pages are primarily intended for presentation logic.
- Code containing Java code, HTML and other scripting instructions can be hard to read.
- The JSP 2.0 Specification is deemphasizing scriptlets in favor of a much simpler expression language. It will be easier to evolve your JSP pages to JSP 2.0-style programming if Java code is not used in your pages.

[Oracle docs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/code-convention-138726.html)

Answer (score 1):

**NO**.Its not a good way.Read more about [**MVC Design Pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)  to understand.

Comment: it's not about safety , but all depends of the organization of your project,jsp are for displaying data,and they should only get results from database ,no logic should be there,so what i suggest as you begin is to create a class that has methods that read from database and update DB and return result to your jsp , lear more about MVC as i suggested.